# Select element inside id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox inside jquery datatable which is created dynamically with the code below.

```
$('#SettingsDatatable').dataTable({
"order": [],
"dom": "Bfrtip",
"buttons": ["copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print"],
"columnDefs": [{
   "targets": 0,
   "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
   return '<input type="checkbox" ' + (data == 'True' ? 'checked' : '') + ' /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#" title="Edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>';

 }}
```

Now I want to select this checkbox with code below.

```
 $('#SettingsDatatable input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function (event) {
                alert("Hello in");
});
```

But its not getting selected.

**Update**

```
$('#SettingsDatatable').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function (event) { 
     event.preventDefault();
     event.stopPropagation();

     return false;
});
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Perhaps your checkbox listener runs before your check boxes are rendered

Comment: Looks like the checkbox isn't yet there on the DOM when you attempt to attach a click handler to it. Attach the handler to an element up the hierarchy (ex: `document`) which is present at the time of binding and specify `#SettingsDatatable input[type="checkbox"]` as the second argument to `.on(...)`

Comment: do you want to make it check the checkbox when you click it???

Comment: @ShakirAhamed I don't want check uncheck to happen when clicked on checkbox. It should be freezed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
$('#SettingsDatatable').on('click','input[type="checkbox"]', function (event) {
                alert("Hello in");
});
```

Comment: Its giving me syntax error

Comment: I have updated my posted with your code. Issue is that my event is not getting prevented. Checkboxes are still can be checked unchecked . How to stop ?

Comment: which event you want to prevent?

Comment: Checkbox click event like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DrKfE/3/

Comment: Use `check` instead of  `click`
`$('#SettingsDatatable').on('check'.....`

Comment: Added ` $('#SettingsDatatable').on('check', 'input[type="checkbox"]`, function (event) {` but result its not working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DrKfE/314/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121518/discussion-between-lara-and-user2181397).

Comment: I am sorry to tell but 
Shared fiddle does not stop checkbox to be clicked.I need to prevent checkbox from being checked / Unchecked.